# Trigger Azure Function with Filtered Document Type from CosmosDB Collection

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

Can we we trigger an azure function only when certain document with field values inserted into Cosmos DB ? E.G an employee document with country "USA" field value trigger azure function. I couldn't figure this one out as its always triggering the function whenever there is an item added / modified which makes too much function calls.

Thanks !

Regards,
Sowmyan

Comment: You may have to implement your own binding/trigger ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the trigger doesn't seem to have any way to filter based on field value, but you can always partition your data into different collections if that makes sense for your case

Comment: Thanks look like only way is move the docs to different collection and trigger it.

Answer (score 1):

Well based on the suggestion from one of the cosmosdb expert from microsoft

> "Right now we don't support filters on the Change Feed but it is in
>   the roadmap :) You can apply a filter within the Function's code as a
>   workaround right now on the batch of received documents."

You can do the above rather than partitioning which is going to cost you much.

Comment: I think moving to a separate collection would be cheaper than putting a filter in Azure function and execute for each insert and updates of documents.