# Service Bus + Azure function/ Invoke the function from WebAPI directly

Tags: triggers, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, servicebus

I have the following Azure function that runs on a CosmosDb Trigger. It takes a Document input and sends that data to another API.
It works well but I have a couple of questions. The Document input/jsonData has a field called type. This type can be "Orders", "Invoices"...
I want the AZ function to be run for insert statements with type="Invoices"
I do not want the function to run for every insert or delete or update. How I configure it in such a way that the Function triggers only for type ="Invoices" and operation="Insert"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger Azure Function with Filtered Document Type from CosmosDB Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49332142/trigger-azure-function-with-filtered-document-type-from-cosmosdb-collection)

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta: I looked at it too. It doesn't help. I have many types that the function need to run on.

Comment: The point of that question is the answer: No, it is not possible to filter the CosmosDBTrigger to only receive events of a particular type of documents.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta: So how do you recommend doing something like this? I do not want the function running for all the inserts and updates. The function should run for type=''Invoices' and operation = 'Insert'

Comment: It is not possible with the current state of things to build such a thing, there is no way to filter server side the type of item activity that should be returned as part of the Cosmos DB Change Feed response (which is the one feeding the CosmosDBTrigger)

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta: I am fine with doing this in the C# code in the Azure function. But what about the operation. I want to make sure the function does not do its processing for updates. I want the function to process only for Inserts in Cosmos DB.

Comment: Already answered on https://stackoverflow.com/a/66819576/5641598

Comment: @user575219 - please note that comments are not for extended discussion. Also, your question has been answered (e.g. can’t be done). There’s no need to keep asking.